# Select query with custom column and value of other column

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I want to have a query that have a custom column and have some value of other column

Here is example of a table

```
Table 1 : id, name, emp_id
```

I want to have input like this

```
id | name | emp_id | process      |
1  | John | 002    | Work of John |
```

The process is just custom column I want to do it in Select query. Laravel eloquent query much more appreciated, since I'm doing it in laravel.

This is what I tried:

```
Select id, name, emp_id, "Work of " + name as process, 
from table1
```

But it's not working. I also want to add 2 or more column value in custom column.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `concat()`:

```
select id, name, emp_id, concat('Work of ', name) as process
from table1
```

Comment: How can I use that if I'm gonna put two column? example I want to put the employee ID too?